# ScikitLearn ML models got cv_results.mean() =0 and cv_results.std() = 0

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset (https://github.com/ivonnics/Machine-Learning/blob/master/CJD2.csv) from my celular data usage indicating: Date, Time and Volume.
From the Date feature I separated the different days of the week (mon - sun) and from the Time feature I considered four (4) different time frames (Midnight, Morning, Afternoon and Evening). With those 11 "New" features, I am trying to find a relation between weekday, time frame and the data Volume used.
I modified a Jason Brownlee (@TeachTheMachine) program (you can download the modified version from my github at https://github.com/ivonnics/Machine-Learning/blob/master/Data%20Analytical%20Github.py) and got as result for all different models used: Mean and Standard Deviation equals to zero (0).I don`t understand why...
Any help or recommendation?
The program:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Nov 10 15:18:54 2018
@author: ivonnics
"""

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix

url = "https://github.com/ivonnics/Machine-Learning/blob/master/CJD2.csv"
dataset = pd.read_html(url)
Tabla=dataset[0]
dataset=Tabla[['Date', 'Time', 'Volume']]

dataset1=[pd.to_datetime(hour, format="%I:%M:%S %p", errors="coerce") for hour in dataset['Time']]

print('-----------------------------------------------------------')
#print('TESTANDO')
dataset2=pd.Series(dataset1).dt.hour
#print(dataset2)
dataset3={'Hour': dataset2}
#print(dataset3)
dataset4=pd.DataFrame(dataset3, columns = ['Hour'])
#print(dataset4.head(20))

print(dataset.head(20))
print('-----------------------------------------------------------')
print(dataset.shape)
print('-----------------------------------------------------------')
print(dataset.describe())
print('-----------------------------------------------------------')


print(dataset.nunique())
print('-----------------------------------------------------------')

print('-----------------------------------------------------------')


df_new1= pd.concat([dataset, dataset4], axis=1)

print('-----------------------------------------------------------')
print(df_new1[(df_new1['Hour'] == 5)])
print('-----------------------------------------------------------')

dataset5=[pd.to_datetime(weekday, format="%m/%d/%Y", errors="coerce") for weekday in dataset['Date']]


dataset6=pd.Series(dataset5).dt.weekday_name
dataset7={'Weekday': dataset6}

dataset8=pd.DataFrame(dataset7, columns = ['Weekday'])

df_new2= pd.concat([df_new1, dataset8], axis=1)

df_new2['Madrugada'] = np.where((df_new2['Hour']>=0) & (df_new2['Hour']<6), 1, 0)
df_new2['Mañana'] = np.where((df_new2['Hour']>=6) & (df_new2['Hour']<12), 1, 0)
df_new2['Tarde'] = np.where((df_new2['Hour']>=12) & (df_new2['Hour']<18), 1, 0)
df_new2['Noche'] = np.where((df_new2['Hour']>=18) & (df_new2['Hour']<24), 1, 0)
df_new2['Lunes'] = np.where((df_new2['Weekday']=='Monday'), 1, 0)
df_new2['Martes'] = np.where((df_new2['Weekday']=='Tuesday'), 1, 0)
df_new2['Miércoles'] = np.where((df_new2['Weekday']=='Wednesday'), 1, 0)
df_new2['Jueves'] = np.where((df_new2['Weekday']=='Thursday'), 1, 0)
df_new2['Viernes'] = np.where((df_new2['Weekday']=='Friday'), 1, 0)
df_new2['Sábado'] = np.where((df_new2['Weekday']=='Saturday'), 1, 0)
df_new2['Domingo'] = np.where((df_new2['Weekday']=='Sunday'), 1, 0)


print(df_new2.shape)
print(df_new2.head(20))


df_new3=df_new2[['Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado', 'Domingo', 'Madrugada', 'Mañana', 'Tarde', 'Noche', 'Volume']]

#Analysis
print(df_new3.shape)
print(df_new3.head(20))
print(dataset.describe())
print(df_new2.groupby('Weekday').size())
print(df_new3.groupby('Madrugada').size())
print(df_new3.groupby('Mañana').size())
print(df_new3.groupby('Tarde').size())
print(df_new3.groupby('Noche').size())
print(df_new3.groupby('Volume').size())
# box and whisker plots
df_new3.plot(kind='box', subplots=True, layout=(4,3), sharex=False, sharey=False)
plt.show()
# histograms
df_new3.hist()
plt.show()
# scatter plot matrix
scatter_matrix(df_new3)
plt.show()

# Split-out validation dataset
array = df_new3.values
X = array[:,0:11]
#print(X)
Y = array[:,11]


#print(Y)
lab_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoded = lab_enc.fit_transform(Y)
Y=encoded
#print(Y)
print('')

validation_size = 0.20
seed = 7
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)


num_folds = 10
num_instances = len(X_train)
seed = 7
scoring = 'accuracy'


models = []

models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression())) #FUNCIONA!!!
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier())) #FUNCIONA!!!
models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier())) #FUNCIONA!!!
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB())) # FUNCIONA!!!
models.append(('SVM', SVC())) #FUNCIONA!!!
# evaluate each model in turn
results = []
names = []

for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)


# Compare Algorithms
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Algorithm Comparison')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.boxplot(results)
ax.set_xticklabels(names)
plt.show()
```

This is the result I got after the model`s evaluation:

```
LR: 0.000000 (0.000000)
KNN: 0.000000 (0.000000)
CART: 0.000000 (0.000000)
NB: 0.000000 (0.000000)
SVM: 0.000000 (0.000000)
```

Thanking you in advance for any help...
José

Comment: Are you sure Y = array[:,11] is points at the correct labels?

Comment: I believe so, I printed the array with print(Y) and got the desired result, feel free to download the program and try by yourself...

Comment: Welcome to SO; please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as why [a wall of code isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/).

Comment: Is `Volume` a continuous or categorical variable?

Comment: Originally it is a continuos variable, but after: 'lab_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoded = lab_enc.fit_transform(Y)
Y=encoded'. I believe it is transformed into a categorical one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your case, that you have 621 **samples** with 593 **unique** labels.
That's why deterministic estimators can not find any learned value to any of your validation sample after `Kfold` (Actually you can find some minimal accuracy with `StratifiedKfold` at `nfold=2` by KNN and CART, but it is not important now).

```
print(len(Y))
print(len(np.unique(Y)))
```

**Out:**

```
621
593
```

Test it and make a trick, actually some funny kind of **augmentation** for testing purposes before of `train_test_split`:

```
X = 5 * list(X)
Y = 5 * list(Y)
```

and your results will be much better right away:

```
LR: 0.015700 (0.000403)
KNN: 0.028583 (0.000403)
CART: 0.018519 (0.001610)
NB: 0.018519 (0.001610)
SVM: 0.010870 (0.000403)
```

So in your original case, at each validation step the estimator will face a sample and will estimate a label probabilities (or label) for it, but will get a validation(test) label which will be different from the learned one(s).
As a result it will return **0.00 accuracy**.

To better understand say we have

```
0100000000 256
0100000000 675
0100000000 912
```

In your **training** set, after it has been splitted into **train** and **test** sets.
The estimator will learn it. Because of the relatively huge number of **unique labels** the **validation** set will contain the following:

```
0100000000 112
0100000000 745
0100000000 312
```

Then it tries to estimate the proper `labels`, to the value:

```
0100000000
```

which will be something like this depending on estimator and its option:

```
{256: 0.333, 675: 0.333, 912: 0.333}
```

So the **validation**(test) `accuracies` then:

```
0100000000 112 at this label: 0.00
0100000000 745 at this label: 0.00
0100000000 312 at this label: 0.00
```

I hope is it clear now to everybody.

Comment: Liked your **augmentation** approach! => More data to dilute the lack of capability from the deterministic estimators to find learned values in the validation samples...

Comment: However, the suggested reason (**having 621 samples with 593 unique labels**)  is not the cause of the problem,  as after inserting `df_new3=df_new3.drop_duplicates(subset=['Volume'])` just before `df_new3.plot(kind='box', subplots=True, layout=(4,3), sharex=False, sharey=False)` you would get 593 samples with 593 unique labels. Even with that the result continue to be: `LR: 0.000000 (0.000000)
KNN: 0.000000 (0.000000)
CART: 0.000000 (0.000000)
NB: 0.000000 (0.000000)
SVM: 0.000000 (0.000000)`

Comment: @JoséLuisMartínez Then you didn't understood my explanation about reason. The last section explain actually what's happening. I add a little more concrete explanation yet.

Comment: @JoséLuisMartínez I am happy, if I could help you José Luis.